# Dojotoolkit store.GetValue when TextBox inside

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

i have a question regarding the dojotoolkit.
I have a DataGrid and want to get a value inside of it. The tricky part is, that the value is a
TextBox.

My structure for the DataGrid looks like this:

```
grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        store: store,
        structure: [
            {
                name: "Quantity", field: "Quantity", width: "30px",
                formatter: function(item)
                {
                    var tb = new dijit.form.TextBox(
                    {
                        name: "quantity",
                        value: "1",
                        placeHolder: "quantity", 

                    });
                    return tb;
                }
            },
            { name: "Value", field: "Value", width: "auto"}
        ]
    }, "bGrid");
```

I have furthermore a button which can be clicked.
If the button was clicked, this function is executed:

```
myClass.prototype.Test = function Test(tItem)
{
    var item = tItem;
    var val = grid.getItem(item.value); //Value in this case is an integer refering to the position of my item in the grid
    var quantity;
    var name;
    if(val!==null){

        var store = grid.store;
        quantity = store.getValue(val, 'Quantity');
        name = store.getValue(val, 'Value');
    } 
    console.log("Quantity "+quantity+ " Name: "+name);
}
```

the name variable is set correctly but i don't get anything from quantity.
I would guess that i would get the TextBox but i receive nothing.

Does anybody know how to access the field of the store ?

Comment: have you tried to set store.getValue(val,'name'); ?

Comment: Yes but i don't get anything

Comment: I guess you have checked if val have any Value at this point...

Comment: val has probably the correct value, at least i get the correct Value when i use store.getValue(val,'Value'). Name is set to 'testValue1' in my XML and this is what i get.

Comment: I think the problem is that i want access the TextBox but i can't get it because it's in the grid but not in the store. Can i acces the fields of the grid otherwise ?

Comment: I think because the Textbox is a widget you can get access to its value by setting an id for it and get the element by dijit.byId("YourTB").get('value').

Comment: Nailed it !!!! this works. If you write an short answer i'll grant you your points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because the Textbox is a widget you can get access to its value by setting an id for it and get the element by

```
dijit.byId("YourTB").get('value');
```

Regards, Miriam